# If I delete the copies stored in my pc will it be removed in my iPhone to?

Tags: sync, iphone

So I have mp3 file stored in my pc, I've added it to iTunes Library already because I plan to sync/transfer it in my iPhone. My only question is if I delete the copies stored in my pc after I've synced it in my iPhone will it be removed in my iPhone to?

Comment: Note to the person(s) who vote to close: This is within the scope as it is talking about a mobile phone connecting to a computer

Comment: I think this would fit Ask Different better that SuperUser. It's not really about interfacing with a computer, but about Apple software behavior.

Comment: It would not be deleted from the iPhone, at least not until the iPhone was synced with Itunes, if something is no longer in the library its removed from the phone.